# In vi editor how i can save words in multiple buffers and use them whereever i want (without copying again and again)

Tags: vi

With vi editor a file say "numbers" is opened with the contents as below, I want to copy these words and use them randomly multiple times in rest of document.

```
one two three four five
```

Comment: @StunBrick Read the question carefully, It implies I know the answer (copy to multiple buffers, don't copy again, etc). Learning has changed now, we need not do research on things already invented. only point is to put short relevant content at one place. I am working toward this in this community. How many using vi know this small piece and they don't use this powerful feature because it is deep hidden in 100 page documentation.

Comment: But did you read the vim wiki on how to copy paste?
http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Copy,_cut_and_paste

It's hardly 100 pages, in-fact your answers are at lines 27 and 34 on the Vimwiki page on cut/copy/paste and its in the first results that comes up if you google "how to copy paste in vim"

Comment: One thing that might have confused you though, is that they are copy paste registers, not copy paste buffers. Which is fair enough.

Comment: Understand what iam saying here, I know the answer just helping others to put relevant info together. when you are focusing on key things don't deviate for silly things like vi options etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
yw copies a word and p (pastes the buffer) 
yy copies a line and p (pastes the buffer) 

("ayw) copies a word into  buffer named 'a' (single character a). ("ap) pastes the contents on buffer named 'a'.
("ayy) copies a line into  buffer named 'a' (single character a). ("ap) pastes the contents on buffer named 'a'.
```

vi has named buffers. If we do yw it copies word in unnamed buffer, so everytime we copy another word it overwrites the contents of buffer. So we end up with last copy we made into buffer.

while copying we can give name to buffer as below

Make the cursor point to begining of word say "one" in command mode (press esc to make sure you are in command mode) type ("ayw). This means the word is copied in buffer named "a". To paste the copied word "one" anywhere, you can press ("ap).

Similarly you make cursor point to second word "two" in command mode (press esc to make sure you are in command mode) type ("byw). This means the word is copied in buffer named "b". To paste the copied word "two" anywhere, you can press ("bp).

Similarly you make cursor point to third word "three" in command mode (press esc to make sure you are in command mode) type ("cyw). This means the word is copied in buffer named "c". To paste the copied word "three" anywhere, you can press ("cp).

and so on.

Hope that helps